# Absolutely positioned block anchor tags unclickable in IE6

Tags: jquery, css, anchor, internet-explorer-6

I hate IE6 with a passion, but since a good chunk of our potential clients still use it, here we go...

For some reason, the anchor tags present on the exploded view of the house (the little glowing lights) are unclickable. I'm having a hard time understanding why. I've tried setting a z-index (both on the parent and the actual anchors of course) but to no avail...

You can see the relevant css/js in the source code (ahhhh what a shitty movie it'll be btw ^^)

Thanks for any help folks.

Here's the link to the test page : http://alarmefast.com/securitasdirect2011/haute-securite.php

Comment: 1. Are the links (lights) at least positioned correctly? 2. Is the cursor changing on rollover? 3. Are the links displayed anywhere - all pushed to the top of the div, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I completely re-wrote the code to get something cleaner, and now it works. Just a really specific problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes, try removing the  tag from the title field in each of the links and test in IE. Not sure why this would be throwing things off, but worth testing nonetheless.

Also, as a IE bug fix, try adding `clear:both` to all of your glowing `<a>` tags.

Comment: This is getting weirder and weirder :
So I added the clear:both to all of the glowing <a> tags. What it seems to do know is that I apparently can trigger the hover event exactly once on each tag, and then it stops working. 
The cursor does not change on hover... (or extremely briefly)